# import * from module named as a variable

Tags: python, python-import

I've got a situation where I need to `import *` from a list of modules which may or may not exist.  So far, I've got a working solution that goes a little something like this:

```
for module in modules:
    try:
        imported = __import__(module, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
        for sub in module.split(".")[1:]:
            imported = getattr(imported, sub)
        for name in  [n for n in dir(imported) if not n.startswith("_")]:
            globals()[name] = getattr(imported, name)
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        pass
```

This works, but is a total mess and confuses linters no end when they're looking for the variables that get imported in this way.  I'm certain I'm missing something in the way `__import__` works, since surely `from foo import *` doesn't generate such a horrible call as I've got above.  Can anyone enlighten me?

**Update:**

The actual use case here is refactoring a django project settings file, to move app-specific settings into a settings file within that app.  Currently, all settings are in the main settings file, which has become unmaintainably large.  I need to retain the ability to override any of the settings defined in that way from another settings file (`client_settings.py`), which gets imported as `from foo_project.client_settings import *` at the bottom of the settings file.

Doing `from app.settings import *` for each app would work, but I want to drive this from the installed apps setting to maintain DRY.

Comment: Wait what? What happens when you do `from foo import *`?

Comment: `import *` *already* confuses linters.

Comment: this is awful ... why would you do this ... just have one file that does all your try except imports normally and then import * from that if you must

Comment: In this application, the modules that I'm exercising `import *` on are simple enough for pylint to handle.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?